# Add Metadata to CSV-Textfile in JS

Tags: javascript, file, csv, header, metadata

I'm creating a CSV-File from a usermade HTML-table using JS. Now it occurs there is information which just has to be added once to the file like the creator or some information of the table (the year the table relates to for instance).

I don't really want to save redundant information in every single row so I came up with the idea to just save a few things in the header or the metadata of the file.

Is that possible? And how?
Later it should be possible to read that in Java again. (Using commons-fileupload but I don't think that will be a huge issue)

Right now I have a pretty generic:

```
function csvDownload() {
    var cna = document.getElementById('usertbl').childNodes;
    var data = new Array();

                    for(var i = 0;i<cna.length;i++){
                        data.push(new Array(cna[i].childNodes[0].innerText,    //ArtNr

                                  //And so on... Much other stuff as well 

                                  ));
                        }

                    var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    /*                
    data.forEach(function(infoArray, index){
                        dataString = infoArray.join(",");
                        csvContent += index < data.length ? dataString+ "\n" : dataString;
                 });
                 */
                 var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent+$.csv.fromArrays(data));
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", my_data.csv");
document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

link.click(); // This will download the data file named "my_data.csv".
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file stores strictly tabular data. It has no notion of metadata, so it probably is not a suitable file format for your requirements. You could either store your metadata in a separate CSV file, or define some sort of "container format" which stores both the metadata and the CSV, but I suggest you use XML or JSON instead.

Comment: Apparently those things are saved: `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,` - isn't there a way to extend that?